# I have problems with "echo" empty in php

Tags: php

I tell you, I have a form where only email addresses are loaded

The idea is that when a user enters for example pepito@pepito.com the page says, "you enter pepito@pepito.com" the problem I have with the echo is that when you enter the page, you show me input "you income ", how can I eliminate that?

```
<?php echo "you income $email"; ?>
```

Comment: Seems that `$email` is empty. Try the code by assigning the static value in the variable.

Comment: you are doing it with form submission or ajax???

Comment: where `$email` is defined

Comment: Include a minimal working example of your html code. There can be several reasons why `$email` is returning empty. You don't expect us to assume one of them. see (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please know that only including a very short code makes your question unclear/ambiguous.
But in your code, it seems like you are only printing it without checking if variable `$email` has value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple example for it

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo !empty($_POST['email']) ? 'you enter ' . $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="email" placeholder="somebody@example.com" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using the [ternary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operator after check the `email` parameter with [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

it will check if form is submitted or not and if submitted it will echo the email.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>

     </head>

     <body>
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
         echo "you entered ". $_POST['email'];
        }
       ?>

       <form action="" method="post">
         <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="somebody@example.com" required 
          placeholder="Enter Email">
          <input type="submit" name="submit">
       </form>
     </body>

     </html>
```